# How to find endpoint coordinates from starting and scrolled point

Tags: ios, endpoint, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have to find Endpoint from start and moved point.

I am doing animation and I need to move `View` when user drag the view then I have to through it out of the screen and bring back to the original point.

Right now I have used **UISwipeGestureRecognizer** for detecting swipe on Move. Following is the code.

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeDown = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];

    // Setting the swipe direction.
    [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [swipeUp setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp];
    [swipeDown setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown];

    // Adding the swipe gesture on image view
    [_view1   addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
    [_view1 addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
    [_view1 addGestureRecognizer:swipeUp];
    [_view1 addGestureRecognizer:swipeDown];
```

**Handling Swipe**

```
- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe {

    CGPoint movedPoint = [swipe locationInView:swipe.view];

    if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
        NSLog(@"Left Swipe");

        CGPoint startPoint = _view1.frame.origin;
        //Diffence Moved
        float movedDiffence_X = startPoint.x - movedPoint.x;
        float movedDiffence_Y = startPoint.y - movedPoint.y;
        //How can I find END POINT BASED ON THIS DATA

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
            _view1.center = CGPointMake(movedDiffence_X *3,movedDiffence_Y *3 );
            _view1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-0.86);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^{
                _view1.center = CGPointMake(84, 240);
                _view1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.36);
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            }];
        }];

    }
    if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {
        NSLog(@"Right Swipe");
        CGPoint startPoint = _view1.frame.origin;
        //Diffence Moved
        float movedDiffence_X = startPoint.x - movedPoint.x;
        float movedDiffence_Y = startPoint.y - movedPoint.y;

        //How can I find

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
            _view1.center = CGPointMake(movedDiffence_X *3,movedDiffence_Y *3 );
            _view1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-0.86);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^{
                _view1.center = CGPointMake(84, 240);
                _view1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.36);
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            }];
        }];
    }

    if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp) {
        NSLog(@"Up Swipe");

        CGPoint startPoint = _view1.frame.origin;
        //Diffence Moved
        float movedDiffence_X = startPoint.x - movedPoint.x;
        float movedDiffence_Y = startPoint.y - movedPoint.y;

        //How can I find

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
            _view1.center = CGPointMake(movedDiffence_X *3,movedDiffence_Y *3 );
            _view1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-0.86);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^{
                _view1.center = CGPointMake(84, 240);
                _view1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.36);
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            }];
        }];
    }
    if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown) {
        NSLog(@"Down Swipe");

        CGPoint startPoint = _view1.frame.origin;
        //Diffence Moved
        float movedDiffence_X = startPoint.x - movedPoint.x;
        float movedDiffence_Y = startPoint.y - movedPoint.y;

        //How can I find

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
            _view1.center = CGPointMake(movedDiffence_X *3,movedDiffence_Y *3 );
            _view1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-0.86);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^{
                _view1.center = CGPointMake(84, 240);
                _view1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.36);
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            }];
        }];
    }

}
```

[image]

When I swipe No.1 view then I can get moved point in **SwipeHandler** (handleSwipe) Method

So I can also detect Direction of Swipe. But my problem is that I have to through No.1 View out of the screen. For that I have to find the Endpoint.

So, how can I find Endpoint from Starting point and MovedPoint ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link fro the endpoint calculation. http://library.thinkquest.org/20991/geo/coordgeo.html